# How to add contents from a list of dictionaries into a table with sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to add one by one content from a list of dictionaries into a table with sqalchemy

```
posts = [
{
    'title': 'Version 8.0 Coming Soon',
    'content': 'As outlined in Ending Python 2 Support, 7.1.x will be the last version to support<br> Python 2.7 and 3.5. The next version will be 8.0 and will support Python 3.6 and<br> newer.'
    
},
{
    'title': 'Install or Upgrade',
    'content': 'Install from PyPI with pip:<br> <div class="installation"><ul><li>Drop support for Python 3.4. This will be the last version to support Python 2.7 and 3.5.</li><li>Multiple fixes in low-level Windows compatibility code.</li></ul></div>'
   
},
{
    'title': 'Donate to Support Pallets',
    'content': 'The Pallets organization accepts donations as part of the non-profit Python<br> Software Foundation (PSF). Donations through the PSF support our efforts to<br> maintain the projects and grow the community.'
},
{
    'title': 'Version 2.0 Coming Soon',
    'content': 'As outlined in Ending Python 2 Support, 1.0.x will be the last version to support<br> Python 2.7 and 3.5. The next version will be 2.0 and will support Python 3.6 and<br> newer.'
}
```

Table of db is:

```
class Post(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
title = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False)
content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
```

Error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: post.installation
```

Inserting

```
db.create_all()
for posts_in_blog in posts:
title_from_dic = posts_in_blog.get("title")
content_from_dic = posts_in_blog.get("content")
inserting_into_table = Post(title = title_from_dic, content = content_from_dic) 
db.session.add(inserting_into_table)
db.session.commit()
```

I hope i find the solution
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

you need to set`id` autoincrement to true or provide the value of it. because you are not providing value of id you are getting this error

so change `id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)` to `id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)`

Comment: I still get this error unfortunately   even after the chenges :---> sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: post.installation
[SQL: INSERT INTO post (title, content) VALUES (?, ?)]
[parameters: ('Version 8.0 Coming Soon', 'As outlined in Ending Python 2 Support, 7.1.x will be the last version to support<br> Python 2.7 and 3.5. The next version will be 8.0 and will support Python 3.6 and<br> newer.')]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/gkpj)<---

Comment: As i am understanding the table never gets filled with info

Comment: If i type this `  try:
        db.session.add(inserting_into_table)
        db.session.commit()
    except IntegrityError:
        db.session.rollback()

` the error goes away, but table still is empty dead

Comment: refresh table? see if  `inserting_into_table` is becoming a proper table orm object or not. otherwise, try to create table from fresh using `db.create_all()` and then add the data in table using python orm like `x = Post(content='<content data>,title='<title data>') db.session.add(x) db.session.commit()` and see the data using `Post.query.all()`

Comment: Booh at this point i don't know what to change in my code anymore. If you tell me how to procced after these it would do me a favor